# Meaning of 'Or the other way around'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "Or the other way around" in below sentence I sow in newspaper.

> You read a book & tell someone you loved it & they go pick it up. Or
>   the other way around.

Thank you.

Comment: If you "swap" you and "they", it will be the other way around, I reckon. But more context would help tell for sure.

Comment: So can I say You read a book & tell someone you loved it & they go pick it up. Or vise versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "the other way around" is synonymous with the originally Latin phrase **vice versa**, which means "the same is true if you reverse the order of the constituents" (making whatever changes are necessary to the grammatical case):

> I like her and vice versa (that is, and *she likes me*).
>
> I like her, and the other way around.

With your example:

> You read a book & tell someone you loved it & they go pick it up.

The other way around:

> Someone reads a book and tells you that they loved it, and you  buy a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around would be:

> Someone picks up a book that you have read, and you tell them that you loved it.

Comment: @James- Unfortunately I did not understand.

Comment: It is 'the other way around' because the order in which the events happened has changed.  In the first case, (a) You read a book. (b) You told someone that you loved it. (c) They went out and bought it. In the sentence in my answer, (a) You read a book. (b) Someone buys a copy of the same book. (c) You tell them how much you loved the book that they just bought.  The answer provided by Tᴚoɯɐuo shows a different way in which an 'other way around' can be applied to your sentence. For the record, I prefer Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer.